# Handling '#' in Request URI in Apache Rewrite Rules

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

It looks like Apache Rewrite Rules are ignoring the '#' in the Request URI.

I want to rewrite the following Request

hptt://localhost/app_name/#Place=abc

to

http://localhost/app_name/#/#ID=abc

And here are the Rules i have tried so far and none of them worked.

```
RewriteEngine on 

  # Rule 1
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} %{HTTP_HOST}/app_name/#Place=(.*)$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule ^app_name/#Place=(.*)$ /app_name/#/#ID=$1 [R,L]

  # Rule 2
  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^#Place=(.*)$ [NC] 
  RewriteRule ^app_name/#Place=(.*)$ /app_name/#/#ID=$1 [R,L]
```

When i tried Rule 1) at http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/ it is working as expected. How ever my local apache is not rewriting the rule

Thanks

Comment: You can't match `#` in a rule. It's not sent to the server. It's only seen by the client (your browser). You can't redirect based on that having that in your URL.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the apache not allowed overwrite rules with .htaccess.

in case you are on ubuntu edit the file /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

and change it to

```
<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

then restart apache

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: No The Rules are being applied as i can see them in the log (As i set the logging level to 9). How ever none of them are matching and hence the request is getting passed through

Answer (score 0):

Fragments are not sent in the HTTP Request Messages by web browser. It's pointless to try work with them in an server side.